# Evaluating the integral of $e^{\sin x}$ from $0 \to \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

$$
\xi = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\sin(x)}dx
$$
We can take advantage of the fact that $e^x$ has a simple McLaurin series:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
Substituting $\sin(x)$
$$
\xi = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin^nx}{n!} dx
$$
Switching the bounds of integration:
$$
\xi =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx \, dx
$$

We let
$$
I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx \, dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{n-1}x \sin x\, dx
$$
Using integration by parts:

$$
I_n = \left[-\sin^{n-1}x \cos x \right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + (n-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \sin^{n-2}x - \sin^{n}x\right)
$$

$$
I_n = \frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}
$$

We can see that we get different results when $n$ is odd or even. We know that $I_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $I_1 =1$. So for any $n$ we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
n \,\textrm{even}\, , \quad I_{2n} = \frac{\pi}{2} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}\\
n \,\textrm{odd}\, , \quad I_{2n+1} =  \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1}
\end{cases}
$$
We can now use this for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx$ in $\xi$:
$$
\xi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\pi}{2(2n)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} \right] + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1} \right]
$$
Merging:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\sin(x)}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\pi}{2(2n)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1} \right]
$$

Comment: so is there a question here?

Comment: @mike no, how do I post an answer to my question?

Comment: Yup, solution looks good.

Comment: A solution-verification question should include the answer within the question post.

Answer (score 1):

.. and
$$
\eqalign{
  & \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{2k - 1} \over {2k}}}
  = {{\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {2j + 1} } \over {\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {2j + 2} }}
 = {{\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {j + 1/2} } \over {\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {j + 1} }}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {1/2 + n} \right)\Gamma \left( 1 \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{  n - 1/2 \cr   n \cr}  \right) = {1 \over {n\,{\rm B}(1/2,n)}}  \cr 
  & \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{2k} \over {2k + 1}}}
  = {{\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {2j + 2} } \over {\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {2j + 3} }}
 = {{\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {j + 1} } \over {\prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {j + 3/2} }}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {1 + n} \right)\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( 1 \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 3/2} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{  n + 1/2 \cr   n \cr}  \right) = {n \over {{\rm B}(3/2,n)}} \cr} 
$$

Comment: @G_Cab Is $B(a,b)$ the Beta function?

Comment: yes, it is the Beta function

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of the fact that $e^x$ has a simple McLaurin series:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
Substituting $\sin(x)$
$$
\xi = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin^nx}{n!} dx
$$
Switching the bounds of integration:
$$
\xi =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx \, dx
$$

We let
$$
I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx \, dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{n-1}x \sin x\, dx
$$
Using integration by parts:

$$
I_n = \left[-\sin^{n-1}x \cos x \right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + (n-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \sin^{n-2}x - \sin^{n}x\right)
$$

$$
I_n = \frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}
$$

We can see that we get different results when $n$ is odd or even. We know that $I_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $I_1 =1$. So for any $n$ we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
n \,\textrm{even}\, , \quad I_{2n} = \frac{\pi}{2} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}\\
n \,\textrm{odd}\, , \quad I_{2n+1} =  \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1}
\end{cases}
$$
We can now use this for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx$ in $\xi$:
$$
\xi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\pi}{2(2n)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} \right] + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1} \right]
$$
Merging:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\sin(x)}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\pi}{2(2n)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1} \right]
$$

Comment: add your answer to the referenced previous post

Comment: Your result is given by *Mathematica* as $$\frac{1}{2} \pi  (\pmb{L}_0(1)+I_0(1))\approx 3.10438$$ where $\pmb{L}_0$ is the modified Struve function and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind